# jquery offset left property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this line:

```
$("#"+genId).css({"border":"2px solid black", "background-color":"white", "position":"fixed", "z-index": "10000000000", "top": (pos.top + h + 10)},"left", pos.left + w + 10);
```

When I remove the left part at the end it works, but when I add the left part the element disappears.

Not sure what is happening:

Full Function:

```
function showPopUp(element){

  var pos = element.offset();
  var h = element.height();
  var w = element.width();
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var genId = ("a" + (new Date).getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20));

  newDiv.id = genId;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);
  $("#"+genId).css({"border":"2px solid black", "background-color":"white", "position":"fixed", "z-index": "10000000000", "top": (pos.top + h + 10), "left": (pos.left + w + 10)});
  $("#"+genId).append("<p> Tag:" + element.prop("tagName") + " || Em: "+ getEm(element) + "em || Px: " + getPixel(element) + "</p><p>Font Family: " + getFontFam(element) + "</p>");

}
```

**EDIT**

Fixed typo in code from copying from file

```
... "top": (pos.top + h + 10), "left": (pos.left + w + 10)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best fix but it worked for me.

I used the `margin-left` property instead of the `left` property and it is working now.

Comment: Hi, are you still interested in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `css()` method wrong. It can't look like that. `css()` method takes only one argument like that(a `string` or an `array`). So this:

```
$("#" + genId).css({
  "border": "2px solid black",
  "background-color": "white",
  "position": "fixed",
  "z-index": "10000000000",
  "top": (pos.top + h + 10)
}, "left", pos.left + w + 10);
```

Should look like this:

```
$("#" + genId).css({
  "border": "2px solid black",
  "background-color": "white",
  "position": "fixed",
  "z-index": "10000000000",
  "top": (pos.top + h + 10),
  "left": (pos.left + w + 10)
});
```

Please read the documentation from **[here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** and you will understand.

It's like `.css( propertyName )`

So you can either have this:

`.css('display', 'block')`

Or this:

`.css({'display': 'block', 'color': '#f00'})`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not at my laptop anymore, if no one else answers your question until I get back I will try to help you.